# Adding to HashMaps in different classes

Tags: java, class, hashmap, implementation

I am doing a school assignment where I need to add individuals to a HashMap, as well as adding "person x knows person y" to the map. We got some code form the teacher, and I modified it a bit now. But how do I add individuals to the hash map in the other class?

there are two classes

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class SocialGraph {

    /**
     * The SocialGraph class stores a social
     * graph and implements * a number of methods
     * to construct and query the graph.
     */

    // The map that stores the social graph
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    public SocialGraph(HashMap z) {   // constructor
        map = z;
    }


    SocialGraph() {  //make a default
        map = ("Nobody", <"noone", "noone else" >);

    }

    /**
     * Add individual a to this social graph.
     * * Do nothing if a already exists in this social graph.
     */


    public void addIndividual(String a) {
        if (!map.containsKey(a)) {
            map.put(a, new ArrayList<String>());
        } else {
        }
    }
}
```

and also the class

```
    public class SocialGraphTest {

        public static void main (String [] args){
            addIndividual one = new addIndividual ("Anne");
            addIndividual two = new addIndividual ("Daisy");
            addIndividual three = new addIndividual ("Bob");
            addIndividual four = new addIndividual ("Charlie");

            one.addKnowsArrow (two);
            one.addKnowsArrow (three);
            three.addKnowsArrow (two);
            three.addKnowsArrow (four);
        }
}
```

I know that a few things are wrong, but I am at my wits end...
Any help is much appreciated! I read the related book chapters twice, but still do not understand it.

Comment: The `addIndividual ` is a class method? Or it is another class. If it is the SocialGraph's method then you must first create an object of it and then call the method.  I will help you with an answer if you want and guide you a bit.

Comment: addIndividual is a method, not a class, but it is in another class than where it gets used..it would be really nice of you if you have time to help me :)

Comment: can you provide expected output ?

Comment: The output should be that i create a map of 'this person knows this person' and that i can use a method called 'knows' where i can ask the program whether person a knows person b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first start with the basics.

If you want to take a look here to understand OOP:
[W3s](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_oop.asp)

I would suggest having an empty constructor which initializes the Map

```
private Map<String, List<String>> map;

public SocialGraph() {
    map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
}
```

Next, you must create a method where you add the contacts of the individual.

```
public void addContact(String individual, String contact) {
     if(map.containsKey(individual)) {
          map.get(individual).add(contact);
     }

     // else you can throw an exception
}
```

And then a method to check if an individual knows a contact.

```
public boolean isContact(String individual, String contact) {
     if(map.containsKey(individual)) {
          for(String c : map.get(individual)) {
              if(c.equals(contact) return true;
          }
     }

     return false;
}
```

Then start from creating an object at the other class
and use the method.

```
SocialGraph socialGraph = new SocialGraph();
socialGraph.addIndividual("Tim Davalan");
socialGraph.addContact("Tim Davalan", "Aris");
boolean isContact = socialGraph.isContact("Tim Davalan", "Aris");
```

This is a very simple solution, of course, you can improve your design and follow
well-known practices and clean code principles.

Hope it helps and if you got any question just ask :)

Comment: that is so nice, thank you aristotelis! i will try to read through it and understand it before i try it out. Really appreciate your efforts!!

Comment: I have now read through it and I understand it now! It also seems to work, and I was able to add two methods to it myself! Thank you a lot!

Comment: I am glad that it helped. If you need anything else just ask. Also, accept the answer if it helped you so the question will be checked as answered. Keep trying and learning. Good luck :)